# Install OpenGL ES and compile code for android

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, compilation, android-ndk

I've just started learning OpenGL ES on android (using [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226471)) and came across an issue of adopting [source](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430226475) code from chapter 5 to existing methods of using jni in android (actually, it also concerns simply running a native GL app). I'm trying to compile the native code to get the .so lib and use it further in .apk archive. But compilation is not possible if certain libs are not present (which are GLES/gl.h, EGL/egl.h, GLES/gl.h, GLES/glext.h).

So the question is how do I install those libs (AFAIU, OpenGL ES and EGL installation) and compile the most trivial native code? (tutorials are highly admired).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've tried the [glbuffer](https://github.com/richq/glbuffer) example as was suggested (slightly changed .mk file), but still no success. Compiler gives me the same result as before:

> ndk-build
>
> Compile thumb: egl <= cube.c
>
> /path/jni/cube.c:5:21: error: GLES/gl.h: No such file or directory // same message for glbuffer when gl.h is being included

Here is the cube.c code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GLES/gl.h>

#define FIXED_ONE 0x10000
#define one 1.0f

typedef unsigned char byte;

extern void jni_printf(char *format, ...);

// Cube static 
GLfloat vertices[24] = {        -one, -one, -one,       one, -one,
-one,       one,  one, -one,        -one,  one, -one,       -one, -one,  one,       one, -one,  one,        one,  one,  one,        -one,  one,  one, };

static GLfloat colors[] = {         0,    0, 0,  one,       one,    0,    0,  one,      one,  one,    0,  one,      0,  one,    0> ,  one,      0,    0,  one,  one,        one, 0,  one,  one,         one,  one,  one,  one,      0,  one,  one,  one, };

static byte indices[] = {       0, 4, 5,   0, 5, 1,         1, 5, 6,    1, 6, 2,        2, 6, 7,    2, 7, 3,        3, 7, 4,    3, 4, 0,        4, 7, 6,    4, 6, 5,        3, 0, 1,   3, 1, 2 };


void Cube_draw() {
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0 , colors);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices); }
```

It's awfully trivial and not working, yet.

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM.so
LOCAL_MODULE    := egl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cube.c cuberenderer.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I flicked through that book and it put me off using Native code.  When I got around to trying it, I just looked at some of the example source, took a sample .mk file and renamed a few things and I was up and running.  Is that book ridiculously over complicated for no reason, or did you have to do things that way before a more recent NDK release came out?

Comment: @Poldie, It's not complex, it just requires double revision. Besides it's outdated a bit, so it tell a lot of stuff redundant for rapid learning, though useful to know. Examples work fine with changes, but when I came to GL I just cant compile it. Java part works good.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those libraries are provided by Android itself. However, setting up your project to find them and compile your JNI (native) code correctly can be daunting.

I recommend using [glbuffer](https://github.com/richq/glbuffer) as a starting project, as it will provide you with a `GLSurfaceView` to draw on and set you up with the proper Android libraries.

The details of linking to the Android libraries are contained in `jni/Android.mk` inside that project if you'd like to give it a shot yourself from scratch.

**Edit** - apparently glbuffer is missing `jni/Application.mk`. Create it and put this inside:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Then the ndk will know to look inside the android-8 platform for your includes. You can change this to other versions as needed.

Comment: I'm able to successfully ndk-build with my added instructions

Comment: Yeah, I added a default.properties file with target=android-8 string and it compiled (the glbuffer).

Comment: Hm.. I'm too slow, yet. :D Thanks for help. As for the book sources, guy compiled with a separate arm gcc and libs pulled from android device, so he used things like EGL/egl.h in it, not sure if it's strictly required or if this lib is being fetched automatically. Will have to check. Thanks again!

Comment: It has some syntax mistakes which compiler brings up, but that's the other thing. I successfully compiled glbuffer, so everything else is my next task of "proting" the sources and will be mostly trivial.

Comment: # The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU

APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9

This solves my problem as well

Answer (score 5):

I searched the NDK for instances of the "EGL/egl.h" header file. This particular example will compile and run on Android API level 15, but some other API levels don't have the header.

Comment: arrived at this question looking for how to compile `EGL/egl.h ` header in Android. This worked for me. Compiled using `APP_PLATFORM = android-14`

Answer (score 3):

I just added

```
#include <jni.h>
```

to
cube.c & cuberenderer.c

Changed

```
(*g_VM)->AttachCurrentThread (g_VM, (void **) &env, NULL);
```

to

```
(*g_VM)->AttachCurrentThread (g_VM, (const struct JNINativeInterface ***) &env, NULL);
```

My Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libgltest_jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cube.c cuberenderer.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
-lGLESv1_CM

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My Application.mk:

```
# The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

And built it on android-ndk-r6

Answer (score -2):

You used the filename GLES/glext.h twice.